# Rails 4 authentication - how to use "authenticate_admin" and "authenticate_user" on the same actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am currently using this authentication setup:

```
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!, only: [:user_insights]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:search_users, :results_users]
```

So if I want to `search_users` or see its results (`results_users`), I need to be signed in as a user.

But I need now to be able to search users (`search_users` and `results_users`) also as admin.

```
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!, only: [:user_insights, :search_users, :results_users]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:search_users, :results_users]
```

But now, even if I am signed in as admin and access the action `search_users`, I am kicked out from there because of lack of permissions.

What am I doing wrong? (overwriting authentication rules?)

Answer (score 0):

In your authenticate_user method you should be authenticating an admin as a user, so either admin or user pass as authenticated. That way an admin will qualify as a user and have the rights to everything the user has.